# How to specify max supply ERC20

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, erc-20

im creating an ERC20 token and i want to specify a maximium supply for my token?

I want to mint 2000 tokens.

1000 of that tokens to my wallet, and leave in the contract the other 1000 tokens.

Is that possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with OpenZeppelin using the following code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract ERC20FixedSupply is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Fixed", "FIX") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000); // Mints 1000 tokens to your wallet
        _mint(address(this), 1000); // Mints 1000 tokens to the contract
    }
}
```

There's some more info in the docs [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20-supply)!

Comment: This is more like a total supply, not a max supply.